# 404 for Custom ttf Font on Azure (.NET MVC 5)

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure, fonts

I have an issue that I have seen previously answered.  I implemented the solutions, but the problem persists.

I downloaded two custom ttf fonts to use in my project, Monterey and Bakery.

Both fonts are installed.  Both fronts are in my content folder.  I've updated the font properties for both so that content copies "if newer" on build.  I added necessary language to my web config file.  I create font-face rules in my CSS.

On my local machine, even when accessing the AzureSites version of my app, the custom fonts appear.  On every other computer, they do not appear and present a 404 in the console.

Please see the pictures below.  Thanks in advance for the help!

[image: This first image is how the site SHOULD look with the fonts working properly]

[image: Font files in my Solution Explorer]

[image: Relevant code in my web.config]

[image: Font properties, confirming that I am copying to the server directory]

[image: 404 error messages in the console]

EDITED to add images of the CSS files.

[image: Here is the solution explorer in full. The relevant font CSS is in Site.css]

[image: Here are the font face rules in Site.css for the custom fonts.]

[image: Here is an example of the implementation of the new font-face, within Site.css]

Comment: I believe there's something wrong with the way you're bundling the CSS. Can you share relevant code for that as well in your question?

Comment: @GauravMantri I updated the question to include pictures of the CSS code.  Thanks for the help so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suspicion is that the issue is the `..`  in `..\fonts/baker.ttf`.

Let's say that your directory structure is

```
content/
   styles/
     stylesheet.css
   fonts/
     baker.ttf
```

so when your html contains

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/content/styles/stylesheet.css"/>
```

the resolved url is `/content/styles/../fonts/baker.ttf` and everything works great.

But with mvc when its deployed, your stylesheet is probably getting bundled and compiled with bundler. The link is probably something like

```
<link href="/bundles/css?v=Mny4y0TdpT_Ey6yWlayc6zrqhuQE-XSEh-dK8IJOsqc1" rel="stylesheet">
```

so then the resolved url is `/bundles/../fonts/baker.ttf` which does not exist. I cannot see from the screenshot if that is the case but that is my guess.

Try using an absolute url such as `/content/fonts/baker.ttf` for the font-face import rather than a relative one.

Also, that backslash is highly suspect. Use a forward slash, backslashes are not a valid separator in urls.